# Login application using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Hi all I am new to Angular, I have to work on login application as of now iam using static json values and my json is given below

```
{
    "records": [
        {
            "Name": "sudhir",
            "Password": "ptg"
        },
        {
             "Name":"manne",
             "Password":"ptg123"
        }
    ]
}
```

Using this Json i have to work on login application so please tell me how to validate this users in my controller if possible give me the answer with code.

Comment: Hi @ChrisHermut Please help me if u know the answer

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms you will find your answer here

Comment: The user validation should always be server side. Inside your web you should check only if the server has validated your user and that you have some user info inside a local storage or a globally accessible variable in order to access it whenever you move inside your app

Comment: because this **can't be overstated**, in the exact words of @Synapse: "The user validation should always be server side. Inside your web you should check only if the server has validated your user and that you have some user info inside a local storage or a globally accessible variable in order to access it whenever you move inside your app"

Answer (score 1):

Since it looks that your quite new to Angular I would suggest looking at:

http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2015/03/10/AngularJS-User-Registration-and-Login-Example.aspx

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C21JNx6hE1w

Or just use any SE. There's plenty of tutorials that will give you a step by step solution to building/validating login form.